# Comparing texts with accents

Tags: excel, excel-formula

the two languages I use most are Spanish and Catalan.

Spanish uses accents on vowels: á, é, í, ó, ú
Catalan uses still some differents accents: à, ...

Many people forget to use accents properly, so that, in practical terms "a"="á" and "a"="à", for example.

Excel is case-insensitive, so that "A"="a"
However, Excel is accent-sensitive, so that "a"<>"á"

I need to make comparisons among texts, as if accents were not there. For example, when comparing "común" to "comun", I want the result to be TRUE. I have looked-up in all the excel functions and I have not found any of them that allows this type of comparisons.

I know that, somehow, I need to use the SUBSTITUTE function in order to solve my problem, but I cannot exactly find out how.

Any hints are much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a two-column table, named *Table1*, for which the first and second columns comprise the accented and corresponding non-accented letters respectively, for example:

| Accented | Non-Accented |
| --- | --- |
| á | a |
| é | e |
| í | i |
| ó | o |
| ú | u |

After which you can use the following formula, assuming the entries to be compared are in `A1` and `B1`:

```
=LET(
    α, A1:B1,
    ζ, MID(LOWER(α), SEQUENCE(MAX(LEN(α))), 1),
    ξ, IFNA(XLOOKUP(ζ, Table1[Accented], Table1[Non-Accented]), ζ),
    AND(INDEX(ξ, , 1) = INDEX(ξ, , 2))
)
```

which, for example, will return `TRUE` if `A1` and `B1` contain '*cómúni*' and '*COMUNI*' respectively.

This can either be copied down to give similar results for entries in `A2:B2`, `A3:B3`, etc., or be modified so as to spill down automatically for other entries.

Comment: Thank you Jos, your answer certainly answers my question.
I am going to adapt it so that "común" is transformed into "comun", that is, accents are removed automatically